# Does Powershell ISE cache files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I've been modifying a powershell module on the fly, immediately running afterwards a script that used it and kept not seeing my updates till I restarted powershell ISE. I suppose powershell ISE is caching at least modules. How do I clear the cache or control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `Remove-Module` and `Import-Module`, or `Import-Module -Force`, or `Import-Module -Refresh`.
Also you can google a bunch of similar topics on SO in like 15 seconds.

Comment: So this is not anything specific to Powershell ISE right?

Comment: no, it is not .